# How to compare date with mongodb iso date in laravel mongodb eloquent query?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I want to get record from data where date is greater than given date. But I am getting problem in comparing date with `mongodb` iso datetime.

Currently I am getting date in Y-m-d format which I want to compare in query and date in `mongodb` is in `2015-10-08T08:01:46.000Z` format.

Comment: you have to create new date using your the date  new Date('Y-m-d') then query it

Comment: @Suresh-ISM can you please elaborate.

Comment: var date1 = new Date("Y-m-d");
test.find({ created: { $gt: new Date(date) } }) or test.find({ created: { $gt: new Date("Y-m-d") } })

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel's Eloquent supports Carbon/DateTime objects instead of MongoDate objects which will be converted internally to MongoDate objects when saved to the database. You could use this date handling package in laravel called **[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)** with your queries.

For example, if you want to query for records from Users data where a mongodb datetime field `created_at` is greater that a given date, say records from today, use Carbon's **[`startOfDay()`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/tests/Carbon/StartEndOfTest.php)** property:

```
$dt = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$users = User::where('created_at', '>', $dt)->get();
```

Similarly, to do a data range query i.e. query for records between a specific month, say October of 2015, use the **`whereBetween`** method:

```
$users = User::whereBetween(
             'created_at', array(
                 Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 10, 1),
                 Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 10, 31)
             )
         )->get();
```

Another approach would be to use **[Eloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#dates)** which allows you to work with Carbon/DateTime objects instead of MongoDate objects. Example inspired from the **[docs](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#dates)**:

```
<?php

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    /**
     * Collection for Model
     *
     * @var String
     */
    protected $collection = "users";

    /**
     * Connection for model
     *
     * @var type
     */
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $dates = array('created_at');
}
```

Which allows you to execute queries like:

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '>', new DateTime('-1 day'))->get();
```

Or natively using MongoDate objects, you could try

```
$start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-10-01 00:00:00"));
$stop = new MongoDate(strtotime("2015-10-31 00:00:00"));

$users = DB::collection('users')->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $stop))->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @chridam I was able to get it done by using MongoDate object.

Comment: why mongodate not found

Comment: @Tuhin work with new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(milisecond)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way for you to compare a date is to use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon).

For example, if you want to get from Y-m-d,

you can just use this:

```
$dt = Carbon::createFromDate(2017,11,7);
```

where 2017 = year, 11 = month, and 7 = day. Replace it according to your needed date.

If you want to get data before current time, you can use

```
$dt = Carbon::now()
```

And if you want to get data from the 1st day of current month onwards, you'll just do this:

```
$dt = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
```

Below is a an example of what I used in my code:

```
$device_data = DB::connection('mongodb')
->table('MyRecipe')
->where('data_date', '>', $dt)
->select('*')
->get();
```

I'm using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb to access my Mongo database.