# date comparison in where clause : in mongodb with lumen

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen

in mongodb date is stored in below format ,

```
"delivery_at" : {
        "date" : "2018-11-15 13:41:38.000000", 
        "timezone_type" : NumberInt(1), 
        "timezone" : "+00:00"
    },
```

**in my search string date is passed as below,**

```
$data = "2018-11-16";
```

**my query is like below for mongodb,**

```
 $query->where("delivery_at", ">=", new \DateTime($data ));
```

> but it not gives me expected result with mongodb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare date with mongodb iso date in laravel mongodb eloquent query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011691/how-to-compare-date-with-mongodb-iso-date-in-laravel-mongodb-eloquent-query)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Eloquent supports Carbon/DateTime objects
for more reference you can go to 
[How to compare date with mongodb iso date in laravel mongodb eloquent query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011691/how-to-compare-date-with-mongodb-iso-date-in-laravel-mongodb-eloquent-query)
hope it help

Comment: I have used  Carbon::createFromDate(2015, 10, 1), but it not working for me

Comment: is it giving any error or output is unexpected update question with your implementation